# In Outlook 2007, is there a way to create an email rule based on the modified date?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

I see that there is an option to create an Outlook email rule based on the date range of the received date, but is there a way to use the modified date?

Why I'm asking: I want to make rules in Outlook that mimic the "Later" functionality of the Mailbox iPhone app.